# Print log lines excluding previously-repetitive lines?

Tags: linux, text-processing, uniq

If I had a log file looking like this:

```
A
A
B
C
C
C
A
B
B
```

I would like to output (remove the immediately-successive duplicates):

```
A
B
C
A
B
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the job for [uniq](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html):

```
LC_ALL=C uniq file
```

GNU `uniq` in some locales can report [first of sequences
of lines that sort the same](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/10517/focus=10527). Using `LC_ALL=C` forced bytes comparison behavior, give you persistent result.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cat /var/log/file | sort | uniq
```

Comment: If you were going to do this you could reduce it to a single command `sort -u /var/log/file`. But no matter how you phrase it, it's still not correctly answering the question.